# Hashem testing a person

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, chofetz-chaim, test

The Chofetz Chaim al Torah says, *Chazal* teach in bereishis rabbah, *"Hashem does not elevate a person to greatness until He first tests him."*

Where in *bereishis rabbah* do *chazal* say this?

Comment: Where in Chofetz Chaim al Torah did this quotation come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't saying exactly what you've quoted, but it comes very close:

> ניסיון אחר ניסיון וגידולין אחר גידולין בשביל לנסותן בעולם, בשביל לגדלן בעולם

The midrash (Beraishis Rabba 55:1) is playing on the word נסה, which means test, but sounds like נס, which means to 'raise up'. Thus, the midrash states that Avraham was being tested in order to be raised up. The implication is that tests are necessary for rising in greatness (for otherwise why would Hashem put His beloved servant through such an ordeal)

Comment: I think the Ramban there has a different explanation - it was to show Avraham his own greatness.

Comment: @jim the question is about a very specific source. There are many other opinions regarding the purpose of the akeida besides for the one presented here and the Rambam

Answer (score 1):

It's actually in [Shemos Rabbah 2:3](http://bit.ly/2aYzJw0)

Comment: Can you add a link to the cited location?